# TreeMap collection issue

Tags: java, treemap, treeset

I am trying to create a program to keep track of College Teams and their sports records(Wins, Losses, years played). I want to use a Map(I opted for TreeMap) and a Set(I opted for TreeSet). I want to read the teams from a file and based on the input, update the database. For instance the line: 1975:UCLA:Brown would increment a win for UCLA, increment a loss of Brown and add the year 1975 to both teams.

The Key for the tree map will be the college names. the values is an object called TeamInfo

```
import java.util.TreeSet;

class TeamInfo {
    int wins = 0;
    int losses = 0;
    TreeSet years;

    TeamInfo(int wins, int losses, String year) {
        // provide constructor code here
        this.wins = wins;
        this.losses = losses;
        years = new TreeSet();
    }

    void incrementWins() {
        wins++;
    }

    void incrementLosses() {
        losses++;
    }

    void addYear(String aYear) {
        // provide addYear code here
        years.add(aYear);
    }

    public String toString() {
        // provide toString() code here
        return " Wins: " + wins + " Losses: " + losses + "\n" + "Years: " +
                years.toString();
    }
} // end TeamInfo
```

Ideally after reading from a file I should get the output:

> Name: UCLA Wins:1 Losses:0
>
> Name: Brown Wins:0 Losses: 1

My Problem comes when I have input like this:

> 1939:Villanova:Brown
>
> 1940:Brown:Villanova
>
> 1940:Brown:Villanova

I get output like this:

> Name:  Brown Wins: 2 Losses: 0
>
> Years: [1940]
>
> Name: Brown  Wins: 0 Losses: 1
>
> Years: [1939]
>
> Name: Villanova Wins: 1 Losses: 1
>
> Years: [1939, 1940]
>
> Name: Villanova  Wins: 0 Losses: 1
>
> Years: [1940]

When the output should resemble:

> Name:Brown Wins:2 Losses: 1
>
> Name: Villanova Wins:1 Losses: 2

There are separate records for wins and losses for each team, when there should only be one record with both wins and losses. I've been staring at my code for hours and can't seem to see why it is doing that. Can anyone tell me what error I am committing and why this could be happening?

Thank You!

Here is my Main Class:

```
import java.util.TreeMap;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Iterator;
public class Records {
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        File input = new File("C:\\Users\\Christian\\Desktop\\C code\\input4.txt");
        Scanner test = new Scanner(input).useDelimiter("[:\n]");
        TeamInfo tester;
        String year ="";
        String winner="";
        String loser="";
        TreeMap records = new TreeMap();
        TeamInfo temp = new TeamInfo(0,0,"");

        while(test.hasNext())
        {
            year = test.next();
            winner = test.next();
            loser = test.next();

                    /*search(test.next)
                    increment win
                    */
            if(!records.containsKey(winner))
            {

                TeamInfo firstRecord = new TeamInfo(0,0,"");
                firstRecord.incrementWins();
                firstRecord.addYear(year);
                records.put(winner, firstRecord);
                //  System.out.println("First iteration of " + winner);
            }
            else if(records.containsKey(winner))
            {
                temp = (TeamInfo)records.get(winner);
                temp.incrementWins();
                temp.addYear(year);
                records.replace(winner, temp);
                //  System.out.println("FOUND " + winner);
            }
                    /*
                    search(test.next)*/
            if(!records.containsKey(loser))
            {
                TeamInfo firstRecord = new TeamInfo(0,0,"");
                firstRecord.incrementLosses();
                firstRecord.addYear(year);
                records.put(loser, firstRecord);
                // System.out.println("First iteration of " + loser);
            }

            else if(records.containsKey(loser))
            {
                temp = (TeamInfo)records.get(loser);
                temp.incrementLosses();
                temp.addYear(year);
                records.replace(loser, temp);
                //    System.out.println("FOUND " + loser);
            }
                    /*increment loss
                    */
        }
        while(!records.isEmpty())
        {
            temp = (TeamInfo)records.get(records.firstKey());
            System.out.println("Name: " + records.firstKey().toString() + temp.toString());
            records.remove(records.firstKey());

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Some general comments that will help you clean up your code: 
1. You have duplicated code when you deal with the map. You should prefer this: "item = map.get(key); if item is null, item = new Item(); map.put(key, item); use item". 
2. Your Item ctor gets the year but doesn't actually use it. 
3. When using collections, state their type - e.g., TreeSet<String> or TreeMap<TeamInfo>, and prefer their interfaces, like Set and Map, to begin with.

Comment: After you clean up the code, it's time to debug. You can use a debugger or print-outs, but in any case, instead of staring at the code, just test it while it's running.

Comment: Thank You for the tips! I ran the debugger and found that the scanner was picking up (and in turn) searching for the return key inside the treemap along with the actual string. I changed the delimitter to /r instead of /n.